# How to concatenate current url host name to a string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to construct the URL at runtime for an image to be displayed.Though I am able to display the image the url is going wrong.i am using jquery for this.

```
$('#SupportTicket_L1').attr({
    'data-val': 'true',
    'data-val-required': '<img src=\'/Content/Images/smilyicon.png\'
});
```

The above one works, but I try to construct the url I get the `windows.location` variables displayed in the resultant src attribute.

```
$('#SupportTicket_L1').attr({
    'data-val': 'true',
    'data-val-required': '<img src=window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/Content/Images/smilyicon.png'
});
```

Comment: Look at `src=window`. Does that look right to you?

Answer (score 1):

quote properly:

```
$('#SupportTicket_L1').attr({
    'data-val': 'true',
    'data-val-required': '<img src="' + window.location.protocol + '//' +             
                              window.location.hostname + '/Content/Images/smilyicon.png">'
});
```